# Is the function with prescribed Fourier coefficients bounded a.e.?

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis, signal-processing

Consider a function $F\in L^2(0,1)$ whose Fourier coefficients are:
\begin{align*}
\widehat{F}(n)=
\begin{cases}\frac{1}{n},\quad &n=1,2,3,\dots,\\
0, \quad &n\le 0. 
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
$\textbf{Question}:$ Is $F$ a bounded function on $(0,1)$, with the possible exception of a null-set?

It resembles a little bit the Fourier series of the function $f(x)=x$, but in the case of $F$ the Fourier coefficients don't oscillate. Moreover, if we consider a formal series expansion $$
F(\theta)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{in\theta}}{n},
$$ 
then it clearly diverges for $\theta=0$. It doesn't disqualify my question though, since $F$ doesn't have to be continuous.

I would appreciate any comments/hints.

Comment: Carleson's theorem shows that the formal expansion converges to $F$ ae.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The idea here is that $-\log(1 - z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {z^n \over n}$, so that $F(\theta) = -\log(1 - e^{i\theta})$ which is unbounded as $\theta$ goes to zero.

Comment: +1: Very nice. ${}$

Comment: Wonderful, thanks a bunch! :]